# PHP Static Binary Build

Tags: php, apache, static, build

I am trying to build PHP 5.3.6 with Apache 2.0.55 using gcc compiler in Solaris 10 SPARC.
My requirement is to build the Static portable binary of php.

Following is the configure statement I used.

> ./configure \
>   --enable-static=yes \
>   --prefix=/opt/genesys/gvp/php \
>   --with-apxs2=/opt/genesys/gvp/apache/bin/apxs \
>   --with-config-file-path=/opt/genesys/gvp/apache/conf \
>   --disable-cli \
>   --disable-cgi \
>   --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local \
>   --enable-bcmath \
>   --with-curl=/usr/local \
>   --with-gdbm=/usr/local \
>   --with-gd \
>   --with-png-dir=/usr/local \
>   --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local \
>   --with-xsl=/usr/local \
>   --with-gettext \
>   --with-iconv=/usr/local \
>   --without-mysql \
>   --enable-shmop \
>   --enable-sockets \
>   --enable-xml \
>   --with-libexpat-dir=/usr/local \
>   --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local \
>   --with-mcrypt=/usr/local \
>   --without-pear \
>   --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl \
>   --enable-maintainer-zts \
>   --without-sqlite \
>   --without-sqlite3 \
>   --without-pdo-sqlite \
>   --with-oci8=instantclient,/tmp/instantclient_10_2

I enabled to build with static libraries using --enable-static=yes but still the output of configure shows negative

> checking whether stripping libraries is possible... no
>   checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether to build static libraries... no

Even if I execute ldd on libphp5 after make and make install it still shows it is referring to libraries externally.

Can you please help me how to do the static build? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just tried

`./configure --enable-static`

and output was

> checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
>   checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether to build shared libraries... no
>   checking whether to build static libraries... yes`

can't say that I understand why you have different result

Can you please verify, it won't enable static building when you use just simple command as I ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I just give

>./configure --enable-static

it works fine. The problem may be in other options that I have used???

Comment: yes, this is possible, do a research and find out if any of added switches causes this kind of behavior